# How I take the name in the selected option

Tags: forms, angularjs

I want show the name in a select input form when I select one of their options.
I create the select like that:

```
<select ng-model="electionEventId" ng-options="option.value as option.name for option in electionEvents">
</select>
```

And I catch the selected item value with {{ electionEventId }} but I want the name too of this election without realize another request. ¿Anyone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: Remove the part `option.value as` and the `electionEventId` would get assigned an object

Answer (score 3):

You can bind the entire object in your model:

```
<select ng-model="electionEvent" ng-options="option as option.name for option in electionEvents">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

*My answer seems to be a little too verbose compared to other answers here, but I hope it helps!*

I believe that you will have to traverse the `electionEvents` looking for the option that has `value` property equal to `electionEventId`.

For example, add this function to your controller:

```
$scope.getElectionEventName = function() {
  var name;
  angular.forEach( $scope.electionEvents, function( option ) {
    // Don't process if the name has already been found
    name != null && return;

    if ( option.value === $scope.electionEventId ) {
      name = option.name;
    }
  });

  return name;
};
```

I haven't tested it, but I'm pretty sure it works!
[Unfortunately there's no how to `break` the loop](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/263), so I put that line in the loop function :)